# 120 Vac, three phase, 400 Hz power supply - how important is balancing load?

Tags: three-phase, load

We have 208/120 V, 400 Hz outlet. Can I use a single phase from the outlet to power my hardware or do I need to maintain equal load on all phase?

Let's assume that the max current draw is around 6 amps.

Please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: Safety first!!!

Comment: You aren't being very clear. It would help to describe your situation more specifically.  As things are, you're asking for *very general* answers, and those are off-topic here.

Comment: 6 A on a 6 A power-supply would be a 100% imbalance. 6 A on a 600 A power supply would be a 1% imbalance. What have you got? Please [Edit] the information into your question and give a link to the datasheet, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the origin of the power supply, in particular the load capacity of its neutral.  Different transformers, converters and generators react considerably different to load imbalances.

It also isn't clear what other loads are on the same power supply that would affect the imbalance.  Unbalanced use of a single outlet provided by general electric utility companies should not really be an issue, and it would be unusual even if you have a dedicated transformer for your house or block if it would not be able to cater to this use case reasonably gracefully.